# Bundle.js file is not seen in folder though browser is giving correct output for Hello World. reactJS, npm, babel, webpack server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bundle, webpack-dev-server, package.json

The bundle.js file is getting generated but not in the folder specified in webpack.configure.json (Where exactly(which folder and path) it is getting put into, is not clear)
The browser shows correct output. There is no error.
I have installed the following from the command prompt (for windows)

- npm install webpack --save
- npm install webpack-dev-server --save
- npm install react --save
- npm install react-dom --save
- npm install babel-core
- npm install babel-loader
- npm install babel-preset-react
- npm install babel-preset-es2015

I expect to see the bundle.js file being created in the sample3 folder but its not there after executing the command webpack-dev-server

The webpack.configure.json file is given below

```
    module.exports = {
  entry: "./app.js",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }
}
```

The package.json file is given below

```
{
  "name": "sample3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "reactjs sample application",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"   },
  "keywords": [
    "reactjs"
  ],
  "author": "abc",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

The index.html file is also given below

```
<html>
  <body>
  <h3>"Hi there this works"</h3>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The app.js file is below

```
document.write('welcome to my first app!hooray!');
console.log('app loaded again!!yipee! hoohoo');
```

My questions are
1) What changes are required to see the bundle.js file getting generated in sample3 folder (same folder as the other above files)
2) Everytime I make a new small application(say toDoList) and put it into a folder say sample4, then do i have to execute the npm init and other above listed commands all over again?

The screenshot of command line after executing the webpack-dev-server command is given below too
[image: CommandPrompt]

Answer (score 5):

When using `webpack-dev-server`, the bundle file is created in memory for development, so there is nothing on your harddrive.

When you want to build the file (so that it appears on your drive), you would need to run `webpack` instead of `webpack-dev-server` in your console.

Example in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
}
```

Run this via `npm run build`.

Does this help? Let me know!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, the bundle.js file has indeed got created. However, the output in the browser is not seen. Sounds like a basic question, but what do I put in the browser URL. When I tried https://localhost:8080 it gave me an Err: Connection refused. Same for https://localhost:8080/webpack or webpack-dev-server. Also, I have removed the scripts: { start:........} line from my package.json.  Another doubt is, I have put the command webpack in the console, What exactly you mean by "Run this via npm run build" is not clear. Incidentally, the turnaround time is superb for the answer. !!

Comment: Please post your entire webpack.config in your question. I will check it and edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: The entire webpack.config.json file is posted above. Since it is a Hello World app there are just 6 lines including the curly braces. In fact all the files posted above, index.html, package.json, webpack.config.json and app.js are entire files and not snippets or extracts of code.

Comment: Let me add one more thing. I have installed a lot of plugins but due to this bundle.js issue, I made this bare bone app to see if the basic thing is working before putting in the presets, changing ports and adding loaders etc. in the webpack.config.json. In fact, at this point of time, what exactly those presets etc mean I am not aware.